# Twenty Fifteen Menu Bar is covered by main content at certain widths

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here look at around `1270px` wide browser:

https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfifteen/

By the way, it's not because of that side bar. It happens on a site I'm working on too:

http://vickyspaintings.com/

Check at around `1060px` wide.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I don't see this issue using Chrome 54. Is this a browser specific issue? I don't see the menu covered however I do see the menu 'collapsed' for smaller screen sizes.

Comment: here is a screenshot. Yes it seems ok in safari but no in Chrome 53 at least  http://vickyspaintings.com/2015.jpg